# GET http://localhost:3000/hello 404 (Not Found)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am following tutorial for implementing MERN but I got stuck with the error that says:
*GET http://localhost:3000/hello 404 (Not Found)* I did everything correct but I can not get around the problem. Below are my files, Can anyone form the community help so I can move forward. I really appreciate your help. Thank you all.

**Frontend Folder: App.js**

```
import React, { Component} from 'react' ;
// import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios' ;

class App extends Component {
   state = {
     hello: null
   }

  componentDidMount() {
      axios.get('/hello')
      .then( res => this.setState({ hello: res.data }))
      .catch( err => console.log(err) )
  
  }

  render() {
     return (
        <div>
          {this.state.hello
            ? <div> {this.state.hello} </div>
            : null }
        </div>
      );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Backend Folder: App.js**

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');


//import the 'routes' file
var indexRouter = require('./routes')


var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


// use indexRouter
app.use('/', indexRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

****routes****

```
var express = require('express');

var router = express.Router()  

router.get('/hello', function(req, res) {
    res.json('hello world') ;
})

// this is exported to app.js in the Server folder
module.exports =  router ;
```

**Frontend Folder: package.json**

```
...
"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000", <==== pointing to localhost
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
 ...
```

Comment: FYI, `res.json('hello world') ;` should be `res.send('hello world') ;`.

Comment: thank your for the correction but that did not help me solve the 404 issue

Comment: I don't see any `app.listen(3000)` where you're starting your server on the appropriate port.

Comment: app.listen is in main folder on file named www files. this file has the port number and that is where ```app.listen(5000)``` is placed.

Comment: as far as you can imagine I installed  the express using the express generator and it structures the files for you.

Comment: res.json is fine no problem with that

Comment: as abdi pointed out add this line `app.listen(8081, function () {
   var host = server.address().address
   var port = server.address().port
   
   console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
}) `

Comment: Your title shows port 3000.  I suspect you're not making a request to the right port and that's why you get a 404 because the server you are talking to doesn't have the route you want.  What port is your Express server running on that has the proper route?  What port are you making your `axios.get("/hello")` request to?

Comment: FYI, I seriously dislike the file structure that the express generator creates.  It makes it harder for beginners to see the flow and solve problems.  I always recommend beginners start with a single server source file and a simple server and your first couple routes and then add other file structure only after your server and a few routes are up and running.

Comment: Then, you can add a more scalable file structure and, if things stop working, you can restore to what works and make changes in smaller chunks to see what broke it.  Jumping right to a more complex structure before anything works makes problem solving much more difficult since you have no working structure to return to or analyze your diff from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, i took your code and first issue is that your request is sent to `http://localhost:3001/hello` - meaning it will take port of your frontend (assume you want to run FE and BE separately, ports 3000 and 3001 for instance) [image]

After i fix `axios.get('/hello')` with `axios.get('http://localhost:3000/hello')`, we get to the second issue. I get CORS issue.[image]

In order to fix this we have to configure `cors` on our express backend - https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html.
Actions: `npm i cors` and add `app.use(cors());`
Now if we re-run our backend with `node index.js` and refresh our frontend page - we get response 200 OK. [image]

And third issue is - you don't have `app.listen()`. `` app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`app listening at http://localhost:${PORT}`)) ``

Ok here is the code. First, i removed all extra dependencies for which i thought are not relevant for this case. Then after i make it all working, i put them back, but on some places i might forgot to return all. Also i put your `get` route directly in `index.js` - so that differs as well from your code (you put it in separate module). As I say, i tried to keep things simple and easy to grasp.

**BE** (i run it with `node index.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cors = require('cors')
var createError = require('http-errors');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var app = express();
const PORT = 3000;

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(cookieParser());
 
app.get('/hello', function(req, res) {
    res.send('hello world') ;
})
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`app listening at http://localhost:${PORT}`))

module.exports = app;
```

**FE** (start it with `npm start` - it is create-react-app - port 3001, because backend runs on port 3000)

```
export  class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    hello: null
  }
 componentDidMount() {
     axios.get('http://localhost:3000/hello')
     .then( res => this.setState({ hello: res.data }))
     .catch( err => console.log(err) )
 
 }
 render() {
    return (
       <div>
         {this.state.hello
           ? <div> {this.state.hello} </div>
           : null }
       </div>
     );
   }
 }
```

Comment: Well explained Stefan!!!, Thank you, I have gone through past this problem with your explained answer. I really appreciate that. Just little not I had used the express generator so it created a file called www where I had port listening ``` app.listen(5000) ``` stuff. Thank you

Comment: @Stefan Zivkovic I don't use your answer. But upvoted because you have explained it well.